# What would be a good way to express "You can't get something out of nothing"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

There is a common statement—well, I least I've read quite a few times—that goes like this:

> You can't get something out of nothing.

I would like to know if this sentence has a common translation into Spanish, and if it doesn't, well, I'd like to have a good translation of it.

"`No se puede conseguir algo a partir de la nada`" seems ok, but it sounds pretty wooden.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, expressions of *procession from* (that is, something results because of something that was) seem to sound more natural than expressions of *obtaining from*. That said, I assume both *could* be equally understood.

The Spanish version of [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nada_surge_de_la_nada) has it written as

> - *Nada surge de la nada*

Other ways to express it might include:

> - *Nada viene de la nada.*
> - *Nada procede de la nada.*
> - *No puedes sacar nada de la nada.*

And, of course, `la nada` can also be rephrased in many ways to be more specific or sound more natural (in context). Words and phrases such as `vacío` or `(a)donde hay nada`,  can help spice thing up.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

At a informal context, you can use:

- `De donde no hay, no se puede sacar` (like *you can't get anything from where there's nothing*)-

I think this fits what you are asking, but it's quite informal speaking. Not to be added to a quarter results report, i.e.

Comment: Just point out that this sentence is usually used for complaining about the inability of someone to do something.

Comment: @Javi true. In these cases it could be replaced by the most common idiom 'pedir peras al olmo' (*ask for pears to the elm*)

Comment: @TomasNarros, I would say "ask for pears from the elm."  I like that expression though.

Comment: In this case, maybe also "Quod natura non dat, Salmantica non praestat" (Lo que la naturaleza no da, Salamanca no lo presta)

Answer (score 3):

En el [Refranero del Instituto Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58444&Lng=0) se puede encontrar:

> De donde no hay no se puede sacar.
>
> Donde no hay, no hay.

Answer (score 2):

In Spain it's quite common the idiom

> Nadie da duros a cuatro pesetas.

A "duro" is a five-peseta coin. Although pesetas are not current anymore, most people over 15 or so would understand this saying with the meaning that the OP describes.

Answer (score 2):

Another idiom in Spanish to express that (more coloquial than the others):

> Donde no hay mata, no hay patata

What literally means where there is no plant, you can't find potatoes.